# I cant install Sonata SEO Bundle in Symfony 4

Tags: composer-php, bundle, sonata, symfony4

I've followed the Installation steps:

```
composer require sonata-project/seo-bundle
```

No problem the install process.

but, the next step in config/bundles.php I must add by hand (normally when I install a bundle the config/bundles.php file is updated automatically:

```
Sonata\SeoBundle\SonataSeoBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

After that I have the next fatal error in my log file or doing "php bin/console cache:warmup":

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Sonata\SeoBundle\SonataSeoBundle' not found in src/Kernel.php:32
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see the 'composer require sonata-project/seo-bundle' install is not finish in my remote host: the console say 'Killed'

There is a RAM memory level problem (I have 512Mb in my hosting).

I solved the problem like this:
- I install sonata-project/seo-bundle in my local server
- I copy the local composer.lock file in my remote server.
- I do in my remote server:
composer install

And now sonata-project/seo-bundle is correctly installed.